# How to evaluate the integral of velocity autocorrelation function for calculating the diffusion coefficient

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, fluctuation-dissipation

I am reading Kubo's review article "The fluctuation-dissipation theorem" ([http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ramsak/km1/kubo.pdf](http://www-f1.ijs.si/%7Eramsak/km1/kubo.pdf))

Could someone help me with how Eq. 2.5 is derived? I am confused with how the factor 2 disappeared.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be disappointed for my poor explanation, and you could try to find a precise derivation by yourself.

Please be focused on the interval of integration w.r.t dt'. In the equation just above (2.5), the interval of integration w.r.t dt' originally needs to be from -t1 to t-t1 while it was stated as from 0 to t-t1. Combined with the integral w.r.t t1, the change of interval of integration made it disappear the factor 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is mostly just an issue of massaging the bounds of integration, or rather just their representation.

First notice:

$\int_{0}^{t}dt_1\int_{0}^{t-t_1} dt'<u(t_1)u(t_1+t')>$ = $\int_{0}^{t}dt_1\int_{t_1}^{t} dt'<u(t_1)u(t')>$

And then convince yourself that:

$\int_{0}^{t}dt_1\int_{t_1}^{t} dt'<u(t_1)u(t')>$ = $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}dt_1\int_{0}^{t} dt'<u(t_1)u(t')>$

Because in a stationary state:

$<u(t_1)u(t_1+\Delta)>$ = $<u(t_1)u(t_1-\Delta)>$